# Retrieve range of records in native query JPA with Indexed Parameters

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Query in JPA repository should retrieve list of cars register between 2 dates/timestamps. I tried 2 implementations, it retrieves records, however not in the range set by 2 timestamps. Is this correct way to retrieve records using Indexed Parameters and `between` or comparison operators ?

**1. using `between`**

```
   public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, String> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
           value = "select * from car_records where carRegTs between ?1 and ?2")
   }
   List<Car> retrieveCars(Long startRegTs, Long endRegTs);
```

**2. using `>=`  and  `<=` operators**

```
   public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, String> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
           value = "select * from car_records" where carRegTs >= ?1 and carRegTs <= ?2")
   }
   List<Car> retrieveCars(Long startRegTs, Long endRegTs);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this query using BETWEEN

```
value = "select * from car_records" where carRegTs between 'first_date' and `'second_date')`
```

Comment: It would not work. I have to use Indexed Parameters in native query.